# Why does mysql database return error saying I do not have access as root user?

Tags: python, mysql, runtime

Whenever I run the following code, I get a runtime error saying that I do not have access to the database. I'm not sure why that is happeining because that is the root username and password that I provided when setting the database up.
Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password="root",
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='Users')
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason this is happeining was kind of weird. The "Access Denied" error does not have to mean that the username and password are wrong. It could also mean that there is not a database at the location you specified, therefore your access was denied. To go about debugging this bug, take the following steps:

1. Make sure that the username and password you used was the actual username and password
2. Make sure you got the host address correct (for example: '127.0.0.1', and make sure NOT to put port numbers inside of this address).
3. Make sure that you have a "port = Your_port_number" in your config options when connecting to your database.

When finished, your code should look something like this:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': 'root',
  'host': '127.0.0.1',
  'port': 8889,
  'database': 'Users',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```